# Automatically signing in with AWS Cognito

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've developed a backend for our iOS app with AWS, using Cognito for authentication. Currently, the app requires re-authentication each time it is launched cold. I can't store the token as they expire too frequently. I'm considering simply storing the email and password and using it to reauthenticate after the user has signed in once, but this doesn't seem like the most secure idea.

Is there a better way to automatically authenticate the user without requiring them to explicitly type in their password each time they use the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Amazon Cognito User Pools, there would be a long lived refresh token available. The SDK for iOS will have a session available so you won't need to reauthenticate the user. It has a getSession call which retrieves the tokens, uses the refresh token to get a new access token if the access token is expired.